# How can we access values of an array added in a viewcontroller class, inside a different UIView class..?

Tags: ios, arrays, uiview

viewcontroller.m has the following code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];


self.array=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"hi",@"hello", nil];
NSLog(@"%@",self.array);

view *view1=[[view alloc]init];
[view1 addSubview:self.view];
 view1.viewController=self;

}
```

and there is another UIView class where I am trying to access the array :
the .h file :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ViewController.h"

@class ViewController;

@interface view : UIView{
ViewController *viewController;


}
@property (nonatomic,retain)ViewController *viewController;


@end
```

and the .m file :

```
#import "view.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation view
@synthesize viewController;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {
    NSLog(@"%@",[viewController array]);
}

return self;
}
```

I checked in other posts of stackoverflow, and the passing of values was mentioned only between viewcontrollers; or the array was declared in the appdelegate and used in the classes(which I want to avoid).

The NSLog in the last code segment above gives null; so can you please help out in accessing the values of this array.
Thanks in advance..!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve  using this code in your ViewController

```
#import "view.h"

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSArray *ary = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"7",@"5",@"3",@"2", nil];

    view *v=[[view alloc] init];
    [v initView:ary];

}
```

And in your view.h file :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface view : UIView

-(void)initView:(NSArray *)ary;
@end
```

And in your .m file :

```
#import "view.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation view

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {

    }
    return self;
}

-(void)initView:(NSArray *)ary
{
    NSLog(@"%@",ary);
}

/*
// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code
}
*/

@end
```

Log value will display this :

```
2013-02-20 20:11:52.731 SampleProject[9414:f803] (
    7,
    5,
    3,
    2
)
```

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
view *view1=[[view alloc]init];
```

calls the desired initializer `initWithFrame:` before you set `view1.viewController`, so what's happening is that

```
NSLog(@"%@",[viewController array]);
```

actually calls

```
NSLog(@"%@",[null array]);
```

or (note that is pseudocode)

```
NSLog(@"%@",null);
```

What you'll want to do is to use `view1.viewController` after it is assigned. The best practice would be to make a custom constructor taking `UIViewController*` as a parameter and use it.

Answer (score 0):

First thing you are calling the `init` method on the view and checking for viewController in the `initWithFrame` method which is never called. (But maybe you are calling the `initWithFrame:` from inside your `init` method with a default frame. :) ). 
Second, you are setting the `viewcontroller` property **after** you have called the init method, so your `viewcontroller` is still uninitialized in your `initWithFrame` method. 
Third, instead of passing the whole of `viewcontroller` to your view to access the array (which kind of goes against MVC pattern), you could probably use just create an instance variable in your UIView subclass and pass just the array.

Then you could follow the answer given by Dilip, preferably using the setter method for setting the array. IMO.